# Show Custom Field "Handleby" on Custom Column in WooCommerce Orders Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I'm trying to show a custom field added to all orders made from the website's front-end called "Handleby" with the value "frontend" via a custom column on the admin's orders page. I was able to create a custom column, but couldn't populate it with my field's value.

I'm following [this guide from SkyVerge](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-woocommerce-orders-list-column/), for WooCommerce 3.0+

This creates the custom field and automatically assign it to orders made from front-end checkout:

```
/* Add custom field for orders created from the front-end */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    $order->update_meta_data( 'Handleby', 'frontend' );
}
```

This creates the custom column:

```
/**
 * Add column "Handled By" on orders page to filter for front-end orders
 *
 * @param string[] $columns
 * @return string[] $new_columns
 */

function add_order_handleby_column_header($columns) {

  $new_columns = array();

  foreach($columns as $column_name => $column_info) {

        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;

    // Create a new column named "Handled By" after the Status column
    if('order_status' === $column_name) {
      $new_columns['order_handleby'] = __('Handled By', 'my-textdomain');
    }

    }

    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_order_handleby_column_header', 20);
/* End add "Handled By" column */
```

This is the helper function to get the meta from "Handleby":

```
/* Helper function used to get custom meta "Handleby" */
if(!function_exists('get_order_handleby_meta')) :

  /**
   * Function to get meta from an order
   *
   * @param \WC_Order $order the order
   * @param string $key the meta key
   * @param bool $single whether to get the meta as a single item. Defaults to 'true'
   * @param string $context if 'view' then the value will be filtered
   * @return mixed the order property
   */

  function get_order_handleby_meta($order, $key = '', $single = true, $context = 'edit') {

    // For WooCommerce 3.0 or later
    if(defined('WC_VERSION') && WC_VERSION && version_compare(WC_VERSION, '3.0', '>=')) {

      $value = $order->get_meta($key, $single, $context);

    } else {

      // Have $order->get_id() check here in case WC_VERSION isn't defined correctly
      $order_id = is_callable(array($order, 'get_id')) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
      $value    = get_post_meta($order_id, $key, $single);
    }

    return $value;
  }

endif;
/* End of helper function to get meta */
```

This tries to populate the column with the meta values. I believe this is where I went wrong:

```
/**
 * Adds "Handled By" column content to the orders page after the Status column
 *
 * @param string[] $column name of column being displayed
 */

function add_order_handleby_column_content($column) {
  global $post;

  if('order_handleby' === $column) {

    $order = wc_get_order($post->ID);
    $handleby = get_order_handleby_meta($order, 'Handleby');

        echo $handleby;
  }
}
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_order_handleby_column_content');
/* End of adding column content */
```

And lastly, this styles the column:

```
/**
 * Adjust the appearance for the new "Handle By" column.
 */

function add_order_handleby_column_style() {

  $css = '.widefat .column-order_status, .widefat .column-order_handleby { width: 9%; }';
  wp_add_inline_style('woocommerce_admin_styles', $css);
}
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_order_handleby_column_style');
```

`echo $handleby` is probably where I went wrong.

If anyone can point me to the right direction, that'd be most helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it does in fact work after I cleared the cache. I'm leaving this post here though, in case anyone is searching for a similar solution.